# Equivalent for Linux's "screen"

Tags: linux, windows, gnu-screen

Is there anything similiar to Linux's "screen"? What I want to do is launch console application created in Java. Then let's say I want to execute command to the running application. For example I want to tell it to exit so I'll tell it command 'exit'. On Linux I can open the application "in screen" and later if I want to tell it any command I can attach the "screen", tell it the command and detach. I don't need screen but I need something that can do this. It would also be cool if I could do it without installing any additional software.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install [cygwin](http://cygwin.com) and within cygwin install screen.